# Converting String to Double in Swift

Tags: swift, string, casting, double

I am attempting to convert a String I am retrieving from core data into a Double. I am getting an error that reads "Value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" If I try to add a ! or ?, I then get a new error "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Double'" Please see code below.

```
 @IBAction func proceedTapped(_ sender: Any) {



    let l1 = loc1.latitude
    let l2 = loc2.latitude
    let lg1 = loc1.longitude
    let lg2 = loc2.longitude
    var lat1 :Double = 0.0
    var lat2 :Double = 0.0
    var long1 :Double = 0.0
    var long2 :Double = 0.0

    if let l1 = l1 as? String{
         lat1 = Double(l1)
    }

    if let l2 = l2 as? String{
         lat2 = Double(l2)
    }

    if let lg1 = lg1 as? String{
         long1 = Double(lg1)
    }

    if let lg2 = lg2 as? String{
         long2 = Double(lg2)
    }

    let earthR:Double = 3959.0

let step1 = acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)+cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(abs(long1-long2)))

let dist = step1*earthR
```

Comment: BTW, Swift can infer the type from a literal, so `var lat1 = 0.0` and `let earthR = 3959.0` are sufficient.

Comment: var lat1 :Double? = 0.0

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your string is correct, or its looks like Double format

```
var lat1  = "4.0"

if let lat1 = lat1 as? String{
   print(Double(lat1)) // 4.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that your string *can* be converted to a Double (e.g. your string is "hello"), so the Double() initializer is a failable initializer.  In other words, the Double(string:) method returns an optional Double.

So decide how you're going to handle such a fail to convert to Double.  For example:

```
if let l1 = l1 as? String{
     lat1 = Double(l1) ?? 0.0
}
```